# Pass Iron Router params to pathFor Helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

When using a `pathFor` template helper, how can we pass `Router.current().params._id` into it?

The following code

```
<a href="{{ pathFor 'myPage' _id=Router.current().params._id }}">
```

gives an error

```
Expected space ...e' _id=Router.current().params._id }}" cl...
                                       ^`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Router.current.params._id` instead of `Router.current().params._id`. Meteor will dynamically check the property values, and if it comes across a function, it will call it.